Tips for batch upscaling images

I need to upscale some drawings for custom sprites. Right now they’re at 501 x 501 pixels and it looks awful! What's a good, free way to batch upscale these images? The ones that I’ve tried so far are bad. Thanks!

Well historically you can not upscale. But you could use AI image generators to do an upscale. THough your sprite should have started life as a vector image to begin with.

Use this upscayl.org

Thank you, I did end up trying upscayl.org, but unfortunately it takes to long and might crash my computer.

Yes, I should have started with vector, the only problem is I am only comfortable using FlipaClip on my iPad. The image is a screenshot that I turned into a png. It’s weird, it looks fine but looks really bad in scratch. Even with all that said, thanks for your help!
